# How is it possible to zip the changes made after a given commit? ( git-archive )

Tags: git, zip, patch

I would like to collect all the changed/added files in a zip file, after a given commit `3c7f...`. The changes made in `3c7f...` should not be included, only the changes in the more recent commits.

How is it possible to do it? I would like to update these changes to a PHP server, where git is not installed. It can not access the internet, only the local network.

Answer (score 1):

Say the first commit you are interested in has sha1 123abc and the top one is 456def

you can do a format patch:

```
git format-patch 123abc..456def
```

then zip all

```
tar cvzf MyPatches.tgz *.patch
```

on the other side you can do:

```
tar xvzf MyPatches.tgz
```

and then apply patches

```
git am *.patch
```

Comment: could not open '*.patch' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: are you on linux or windows?

Comment: Windows. And git is not initialized on the server, only the files are there

Comment: could you explain a bit more your setup, where is the tree, where are the files and where/how they are supposed to go. Seems to me you want to use git where it is not available... I must have missed something

Comment: Yes. The development code is stored on github, and we push the changes there. But the production server runs on a windows machine, which can only be accessed with remote desktop ( with VPN ). It does not access the internet, so it can not pull changes from our github server. We have to copy the changed files manually, but I would like to make it easier somehow.

Comment: do you have a ssh conection beween you windows and its administrating machine? if so you could clone it from there (or just add it as remote. That said, if you are looking for deploying your software, it is probably time to package it properly and deploy it with tools that are makde for. I'm sure you will ba able to achieve you patch copies via git, but nt sure it is the best way to do it...

Comment: I am not able to ssh to the linux host machine. Sadly I can only connect to the windows server via remote desktop

Comment: how did you planned to pass the zip archive to the windows machine?

Comment: I can copy-paste to the remote desktop